# pytest make unit tests execution independent from each other

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am trying to develop a python test environment using `pytest` where I have some test functions as follows:

```
from my_app import __main_app__

def run_main_application(var):
    __main_app__.execute_python_script(var)

def test_firts():
    run_main_application("setting1")

def test_second():
    run_main_application("setting2")
```

Basically for each test, the `__main_app__` python application which is handled in `execute_python_script(var)` is executed with a specific setting and configuration defined in `var`.

Everything is working as expected but the execution of the second test is affected by the all variables and settings of the first one. This means that the two executions are not independent.

Is there a way to make each test unit independent from the others? I would expect that `__main_app__` initialization/definition inside def `run_main_application(var)` to be deleted once the method is ended.

Answer (score 0):

Adding fixture could help in your case,

```
@pytest.fixture # @pytest.fixture(scope='function') default scope
def run_main_application():
    return __main_app__.execute_python_script

def test_firts(run_main_application):
    run_main_application("setting1")

def test_second(run_main_application):
    run_main_application("setting2")
```

Comment: this is not working. Reported error is "Fixtures are not meant to be called directly, but are created automatically when test functions request them as parameters."

Comment: Please check the updated edit

Comment: Thanks for the help, however with the last edit I am not passing the variable "setting" that needs to be handled inside execute_python_script() and the execution is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I mange to solve this using the reload function as follows:

```
__main_app__ = reload(__main_app__)
```

This is applied at the end of the `run_main_application(var)` method. Thus:

```
from my_app import __main_app__

def run_main_application(var):
    __main_app__.execute_python_script(var)
    __main_app__ = reload(__main_app__)

def test_firts():
    run_main_application("setting1")

def test_second():
    run_main_application("setting2")
```

In this manner, all the test executions are independent from each other.